# Adding Labels to doughnut chart using canvasjs

Tags: canvasjs

I want to add labels and a legend to my chart but im struggling. Im pulling Data Points from a txt file. that looks like this:

```
77
37
```

The doughnut chart comes out fine i just need to add labels this is the syntax im using:

```
    $.get("graph.txt", function(data) {
    var xVal = 0;
    var allLines = data.split('\n');
    var dps = [];

    for(var i=0; i< allLines.length; i++) {
      xVal +=.25;
      dps.push({x : xVal, y: Number(allLines[i])});
    }

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{

     title:{
     text: "Android"
     },
     data: [
     {
     type: "doughnut",
     indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
     startAngle: 90,  //vary the angle here.
     dataPoints: dps


    }]
 });
chart.render();
},'text');
```

i was trying to just add the labels at the end like this?:

```
chart.render();


chart.data[0].addTo("dataPoints", {y: , label: "Apple" });
```

Comment: You missed the value of **y** in addTo().

Comment: @Beevk I know because the values are coming from a file.

Comment: Other would be nice to just insert as a variable dps but it doesn't work

Comment: You can't leave the value empty even if it comes later from any other source.

Comment: You can modify your dps and add indexLabel there though.

Answer (score 3):

Add to can be used for adding new dataPoints. But in your case, you are just adding indexLabel / label to the existing dataPoints. You can modify your array (**dps**) and add label there after creation of dataPoints.

```
dps[1].indexLabel = "Apple";
dps[2].indexLabel = "Orange";
```

etc...
Or if you know your labels during creation, you can change your statement **dps.push()** and add labels there.

```
dps.push({x : xVal, y: Number(allLines[i]), indexLabel: "Apple"});
```

Comment: Thank you so much im definitely making progress and understanding more. How ever this code make 3 labels on the donut chart and they are all the same. The chart only takes two values and both should have seprate labels.                                                                                                                                                           dps.push({x : xVal, y: Number(allLines[i]), indexLabel: "Apple"});

Comment: index starts from 0 for an array. So, you can try **dps[0].indexLabel** and so on.